# MySQL: Different conditions for each INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query

```
SELECT n.* FROM notifications as n
  INNER JOIN notifications as nc ON ...  ...
     INNER JOIN following as f ON ...  ...
         WHERE
           (condition 1)
                OR
                  (condition 2)
```

My guestion is how i can make sure that condition 1 is evaluted for the first inner join (nc) and condition 2 is evaluted for the second inner join (f)

Comment: Just use the correct alias of table prepended to column name each condition

Comment: Please share the real query. Your question does not make a lot of sense. The concept behind JOINs is that you're combining two table rows into one. With 2 JOINs, you are combining 3 rows into one. THEN, the WHERE clause, filters those "combined rows". There is not a concept of a WHERE clause per JOIN. (Maybe you should also share sample data and the result set you are trying to achieve.)

Comment: i dont need to combine 3 rows into one i want to get notifications by joining following table with notifications and notications with notifications.

Comment: What kind of conditions do you mean? You can put them into the "ON"- clause, but on inner joins it is equivalent with where-conditions. I agree that you should give information about the conditions.

Comment: i need to get notifications for adding posts by joining notification table with following table and to get notifications for adding comment by joining notification table with itself. sould i use UNION for each inner join?

Comment: The above _pseudo-_ query is combining a row from notifications with another row (or multiple rows) from notifications with another row (or multiple rows) from following. The only way anyone is going to be able to help you is if you share the real query, real data and the result set you want. Otherwise we are guessing what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to move you conditions from WHERE clause to ON clause. In case on Inner Join, WHERE and ON work in same manner and it is always better to filter out data as early as possibly in the query.
So, your query will look like:
SELECT n.* FROM notifications as n
  INNER JOIN notifications as nc ON ...  ... AND (Condition 1)
     INNER JOIN following as f ON ...  ... AND (Condition 2)